# Python - Where to paste files to import

Tags: python, import, importerror

First of all let me tell you that I'm a new user and I'm just starting to learn Python in College so my apologies if this question is answered in other topic, but I searched and I can't seem to find it.

I received a file `work.pyc` from my teacher and he says I have to import it in my Wing IDE using the command `from work import *`, the question is I don't know where to put the file to import it.

It just says `ImportError: No module named work`.

Thank you

Comment: I'm a little worried that your teacher is 1) Giving you a `.pyc` file and 2) isn't giving sufficient instructions on how to import it!

Comment: What @JonClements said + "3) is advising `import *`"

Answer (score 3):

There are several options for this.
The most straightforward is to just place it in the same folder as the py file that wants to import it.

You may also want to have a look at [this](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#compiled-python-files)

Comment: Fast and simple answer. It's done! Thanks a lot, I hope I can start helping out people aswell. Thankyou

Answer (score 2):

If you're working on a script called `main.py` in the folder `project`, one option is to place it at `project/work.pyc`

This will make the module importable because it's in the same working directory as your code.

The way Python resolves import statements works like this (simplified):

The Python interpreter you're using (`/usr/bin/python2.6` for example, there can be several on your system) has a list of search paths where it looks for importable code. This list is in `sys.path` and you can look at it by firing up your interpreter and printing it out like this:

```
>>> import sys
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(sys.path)
```

`sys.path` usually contains the path to modules from the standard library, additional installed packages (usually in site-packages) and possibly other 3rd party modules.

When you do something like `import foo`, Python will first look if there is a module called `foo.py` in the directory your script lives. If not, it will search `sys.path` and try to import it from there.

As I said, this explanation is a bit simplified. The details are explained in the section about the [module search path](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path).

**Note 1:**
The `*.pyc` you got handed is [compiled Python bytecode](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#compiled-python-files). That means it's contents are binary, it contains instructions to be executed by a Python virtual machine as opposed to source code in `*.py` that you will normally deal with.

**Note 2:**
The advice your teacher gave you to do `from work import *` is rather bad advice. It might be ok to do this for testing purposes in the interactive interpreter, but your should *never* do that in actual code. Instead you should do something like `from work import chop, hack`

Main reasons:

- **Namespace pollution**. You're likely to import things you don't need but still pollute your global namespace.
- **Readability**. If you ever read someone elses code and wonder where `foo` came from, just scroll up and look at the imports, and you'll see exactly where it's being imported from. If that person used `import *`, you can't do that.

Answer (score 2):

if you're using the python interpreter (the one that lets you directly input python code into it and executes) you'll have to do this:

```
sys.path.append('newpath')

from work import *
```

where **newpath** is the path on your filesystem containing your work.pyc file